# 'Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions' error in Redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-toolkit

calculatorSlice code calculatorSlice.js

```
const initialState = {
  display: 0,
  currentOperand: null,
  previousOperand: null,
  currentOperator: null
};

export const calculatorSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'calculator',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getDisplay (state) {
      return state.display;
    },
    enterDigit (state, action) {
      if (state.display !== '0') {
        [ ...state.display ].concat(action.payload);
      }
      else {
        state.display = action.payload;
      }
      state.currentOperand = parseFloat(state.display);
    }
  }
});
```

[This is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci1AZ.png)

Dispatching action here app.js

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { enterDigit, getDisplay } from './features/calculatorSlice';

const App = () => {
  const state = useSelector(state => state.calculator);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="top-container">
        <h1>{state.display}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-container">
        <button onClick={useDispatch(enterDigit('1'))}>1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

when I click on the button having value `1`, nothing happens. The `state.display` does not update and also it gives me the error mentioned above.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: You cannot call `useDispatch()` into the `onClick` like that...
You need to something like that: const dispatch = useDispatch();
Then you can use your new dispatch on the onClick function

Answer (score 0):

you cannot dispatch an action that is not a plain Javascript object..
Try to update your code like this:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { enterDigit } from './features/calculatorSlice';

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const state = useSelector(state => state.calculator);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="top-container">
        <h1>{state.display}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="bottom-container">
        <button onClick={() => dispatch(enterDigit('1'))}>1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: hello , please little bit explain it what's and where the error and what the error says , Thanks!

Comment: It was the comment above...
You cannot call useDispatch() into the `onClick` like that... You need to do something like that: `const dispatch = useDispatch();` Then you can use your new dispatch on the onClick function

Comment: Think about the other React hooks, you cannot set a state like this: `useState(10)`
You have to declare your state like this: `const [test, setTest] = useState()` and then set your state with the `setState` function: `setTest(10)`

Comment: Have a look to the official docs too! https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch

Comment: ok thank you i understand it now , basically i am beginner to stackoverflow that's why.*Thanks alot*

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it was useful to you and if it fixes your error!